# How to list all all tinyMCE instances on a page

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is there a way to list all instances of tinyMCE on a page?

I add tinyMCE dynamically to a page. I would like to run a command to list of all of the instances that have been created on a page.

```
            tinyMCE.init({ elements: "field1", ...tinyMCE_init});
        </script>
        <textarea name="field1" id="field1" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
```

```
            tinyMCE.init({ elements: "familyConsent", ...tinyMCE_init});
        </script>
        <textarea name="field2" id="field2" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
```

```
            var tinyMCEElementIDs = ????;
            alert("tinyMCE Element ID's on page are: " + tinyMCEElementIDs.join());
       </script>
```

I started by collecting the element ID's in an array but I want to dynamically create that array.

Answer (score 7):

In TinyMCE 6 the `get()` API can provide you an array of all editors on the page:

```
tinymce.get()
```

This will return an array you can iterate over to get access to all TinyMCE instances.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid this "fire and forget" inline scripts to create TinyMCE instances. Mark the textareas with a JS class instead to iterate over them.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jf6eb1zy/

```
const tinySelectors = [];

document.querySelectorAll('.js_tinymce').forEach(element => {
   tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + element.id
   });
   tinySelectors.push(element.id);
});

tinymce.get(tinySelectors[0]);
```

Comment: I added the this right above the </body> tag and nothing was returned.

`<script>
    const tinySelectors = [];

    document.querySelectorAll('.js_tinymce').forEach(element, index) => {
       element.setAttribute('data-tinymce', index);
       tinymce.init({
          selector: '[data-tinymce="' + index + '"]'
       });
       tinySelectors.push();
    }

    alert(tinymce.get(tinySelectors[0]));
</script>


</body>`

Comment: Sorry, I should have tested the code before publishing... there is a demo now